# JSP scripting questions

Tags: jsp

I'm studying SWCD by Charles Lyons (2nd edition) and i'm reviewing some questions about JSP. On page 262, here's the following question:

Which of the following cause the value 'yes' to be written to the response if the state scripting variable is true and 'no' otherwise?

A. `<%=
if (state) {
"yes";
} else {
"false";
}
%>`

B. `<%=state? "yes" : "no"%>`

C. `<% if (state) %>yes<%else%>no`

D. `<% if (state) out.write("yes");
else out.write("no");%>`

E. `<% state? out.write("yes") : out.write("no");%>`

Answer is B & D. I do understand the explanation to the answer given. However nothing is mention about why A is incorrect? I don't see why A is incorrect.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the difference between the expression ( `<%= expressions %>` ) and scriptlets ( `<% code %>`) .

For the expression  ,anything inside `<%=  %>` will be get evaluated to a string and this string is inserted into the servlet's output stream directly when the JSP is converted to the servlet. So  `<%= expressions %>` will convert to  `out.println(expressions)`. There should be no semicolon at the end of the expression , because `out.println(expressions;)` has the syntax error after the JSP is converted to the servlet.

For the scriptlets  , anything inside `<%  %>` will directly inserted as raw Java code in the service method of the generated Servlet. So `<% code(); %>` will convert to `code();`

So , for the option A , `<%= if (state) { "yes"; } else { "false"; } %>` will convert to the `out.println(if (state) { "yes"; } else { "false"; } )` , which have syntax error   .So A is incorrect

Comment: i think the issue here is that statement if (state) { "yes";} else {"false"} will give syntax error in Java. Thanks for your tip.